# Refresh selectmenu - TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery19105462655627634376' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, jquery-mobile

Given the function:

```
function pintarTipologias() {
console.log("pintarTipologias");
$('#comboTipologias').selectmenu();
var tipologias = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tipologias"));
if (tipologias != null && tipologias.length > 0) {
    tipologias.forEach(function(tipologia, posicion) {
        $("#comboTipologias").append('<option value=' + tipologia.id +  '>' + tipologia.denominacion + '</option>');
    });
}
$('#comboTipologias').selectmenu();
$('#comboTipologias').selectmenu("refresh");
}
```

The last line produces the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery19105462655627634376' of undefined

I wrote in the Chrome console:

```
$('#comboTipologias').selectmenu("refresh");
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery19105462655627634376' of undefined
$('#comboTipologias').selectmenu();
[<select id=​"comboTipologias" name=​"comboTipologias" data-mini=​"true" data-native-menu=​"false" multiple=​"multiple" tabindex=​"-1">​…​</select>​]
$('#comboTipologias').selectmenu("refresh");
[<select id=​"comboTipologias" name=​"comboTipologias" data-mini=​"true" data-native-menu=​"false" multiple=​"multiple" tabindex=​"-1">​…​</select>​]
```

I don't understand it

Comment: It seems as though you are storing JSONP in your localstorage rather than JSON. That's a very odd thing to do though. `jQuery19105462655627634376` looks very much like a jsonpcallback value.

Comment: Do you actually have a selectmenu or is it a listview?

Comment: @epascarello selectmenu
`code`<div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <label for=comboTipologias class="remarcado">Características (tip):</label>
     <select id="comboTipologias" name="comboTipologias" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple">
     </select>
    </div>`code`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#comboTipologias').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: I had tried it, but it doesn't work.
I had found the problem: to use a multiple select of JQM. Refresh via javascript crash (but not in console).
I had found and alternative view (checkboxes). More ugly but "dinamyc". Thank you